# single anchor tag when click on button redirect with first id as seen in url and second as hidden

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, codeigniter

This is search.php view code:

```
<p class="center-align">
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger  hoverable" href="<?php echo base_url();?>broucher_request/<?php 
                              echo $res->collg_id ?>/<?php 
                              $res->pdf_name ?>">

        <i class="material-icons left">arrow_downward</i>Brochure</a>

    <!--  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn orange modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>-->
</p>
```

This is brochure_request.php

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">pdf</i>
    <input id="icon_prefix active" type="text" name="pdf_id">
    <label for="icon_prefix">pdf Name</label>
    <div class="white-text center"></div>
</div>
```

This is controller

```
 public function broucher_request($id)
 {
     $data['college_id'] = $id;
     $this->load->view('home/brochure_request',$data);
}
```

i have a anchor tag where i m trying to send collg_id of search.php  and it is redirect me to brochure_request page and now i trying to send one more pdf_name after collg_id like this http://localhost/aplus/broucher_request/44/hello.pdf but in url hello.pdf should be hidden from user and only this much part of url should be seen

```
http://localhost/aplus/broucher_request/44.
```

and on brochure_request page the i have a input tag pdf as input text and on input text i should get name of the pdf.

Comment: try to encode the file and send

Comment: @DanishAli can u encode the url in my code

Comment: You need to encode only PDF file name not complete URL. Follow this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: @DanishAli and one more thing i have one input text pdf on second page where name of the pdf is hidden in url ....i want to display the name of the pdf or path of the file on input text

Comment: Get the pdf name from URL and display in the input field

Comment: @Danish Ali $route['broucher_request/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'home/broucher_request/$1/$2'; saying page not found ....second is pdf file.....

Comment: @Danish Ali i m getting the name in url ...but how to display the name in input file

Comment: share the actual URL

Comment: @DanishAli http://localhost/aplus/broucher_request/44/Y29sbGVnZV8tX0NvcHkucGRm

Comment: get file name like this `$this->uri->segment(2);`

Comment: @DanishAli i m getting the name of the file and now i want to get the path of the file also from where i can now send the file name as link and then to email it

Comment: get the file like this `base_url('path/to/directory/file-name');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<p class="center-align">
   <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger  hoverable" 
     href="<?php echo base_url('broucher_request/'.$res->collg_id.'/'.base64_encode($res->pdf_name));?>">
   <i class="material-icons left">arrow_downward</i>Brochure</a>
 </p>
```

**Controller**

```
public function broucher_request($id, $file)
{
     $data['file'] = base64_decode($file);
     $data['college_id'] = $id;
     $this->load->view('home/brochure_request',$data);
}
```